# Flow of control is not waiting at dialog box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have put up a dialog box in a page and I want a function to be executed on the click of OK button on the dialog box. Also I want, the code below the dialog box to be executed only after the function under OK button is clicked.

But I found that even before I click on the OK button the control has executed the code below the dialog box.

Below is the code.

```
var confirmationFlag =  false;
alert("alertbox1");

$("#confirmdialog").dialog("open");
alert("alertbox2");

$("#ui-dialog-title-confirmdialog").html("Delete this transaction?");
$("#confirmdialog").html("Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?");

$("#confirmdialog_Ok-button").unbind("click").click( function () { 
    confirmationFlag = true;
    alert("alertbox3" +confirmationFlag);
    $("#confirmdialog").dialog("close");            
});

alert("alertbox4 " +confirmationFlag);
```

Ideally I expected the flow to be like
alertbox1 > alertbox2 > alertbox3 > alertbox4

But the flow goes like this
alertbox1 > alertbox2 > alertbox4 > alertbox3

alertbox4 is executed even when the dialog box is open and before clicking on OK button on the dialog box.

Any help on how to proceed to hold the control before clicking on OK is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alert("alertbox3" +confirmationFlag);` is called within the *click event handler* so it won't be displayed until you click.

To get the order you want, you have to move the alert call outside of the click function, just like the other alert calls. Please note that if you move it outside, `confirmationFlag` will still be `false` as the click handler has  not been called yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anders.
I just figured out the logic that I was writing was wrong.
I have to write my entire function within the function executed for click on OK.